# How do you retrieve list of users sorted by reputation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, sort

I am failing in my attempt to retrieve results sorted by reputation.  For example, the following query sorts the results by ID.  Is there an error in the URI?

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/100%3B90%3B80%3B70%3B60/?sort=reputation&order=desc

**Edit** I played with it a bit more and it appears the sort option is not used.  [Sorting by name](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/100%3B90%3B80%3B70%3B60/?sort=name) produces the same results.  It is verified, however.  Specifying an invalid sort option produces a 4002 error.

Comment: This does indeed appear to be a bug and I have retagged your question accordingly.

Comment: @George:  Thanks for looking at it.  It seemed like a bug. However, I have learned that 99% of the time that I think I find a bug in software I am using it turns out instead that I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, sorts weren't being applied to that route.  This should be fixed now.